# How should a backend developer showcase his/her projects?

Tags: attracting-clients, portfolio, proposal

I have registered as a freelancer and yet to start my career. In all the proposals, I have been questioned to showcase my skills(Mostly sql and PLSQL) with some sample work. I have no idea what kind of portfolio/sample work will be impressive and will also showcase my skills?

I have seen many front end developers' sharing applications/websites they have developed. But its not  possible for a backend developer like me to display a database without a front end. To a person hiring, it might look like data (Lot of data) and nothing interesting. So when recruiter asks to show a sample of my work, what do I do? Just show them my queries or scripts might not interest a person. (Am I wrong?)

What kind of Sample should I present to the recruiters that will gain their attention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you showcase how you've been efficient?

> A customer had a query that ran for over 3 minutes to retrieve the data. After detailing the requirements, I was able to run a query to produce the same results in only 3 seconds, making their systems run 60x more efficiently

Would something like that work for you? As a person who appreciates efficiency, it's very easy to see that your solution would scale well, as opposed to the previous solution that made us wait for a long time.

Comment: @Valli you should produce some "case studies" of real life scenarios (or projects that you have developed), then explain them in the most proper way to hilight your skills and knowledges, so people (experts or not) will be able to see what you can do for them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_study

Answer (score 3):

For a back-end developer, I believe your portfolio would be the enterprises and the scale of the projects you worked on. Even though I am a front-end developer, I'm not really focused on integrating websites or designing apps but more on implementing business logic in JS. So every time I have to sell myself, I always talk about the size of the clients, the complexity of the projects, why it was difficult, how did I overcome the problems, etc. That's somehow my "portfolio".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show this to a non technical person build ERM's and UML's that should be enough to show them your knowledge with databases
Say some stuff like: "x table works for y module in the app so it's a critical component for operation etc etc"

If the person has knowledge then build a repository and upload a lot of basic stored procedures, functions, backup automation, replication, basic queries etc.